# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Помогите, пожалуйста. Чистил кэш, удалял приложение на телефоне. Отключил мгновенный запуск. Ничего не исправило проблему.

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bogsnebes.host_bot, PID: 12381
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sedmelluq/discord/lavaplayer/tools/GarbageCollectionMonitor;
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.<init>(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:121)
        at com.bogsnebes.host_bot.bot.Bot.<init>(Bot.kt:26)
        at com.bogsnebes.host_bot.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:11)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2615)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.tools.GarbageCollectionMonitor
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.<init>(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:121) 
        at com.bogsnebes.host_bot.bot.Bot.<init>(Bot.kt:26) 
        at com.bogsnebes.host_bot.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:11) 
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2615) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/management/NotificationListener;
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.<init>(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:121) 
        at com.bogsnebes.host_bot.bot.Bot.<init>(Bot.kt:26) 
        at com.bogsnebes.host_bot.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:11) 
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2615) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.management.NotificationListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bogsnebes.host_bot-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.bogsnebes.host_bot-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.sedmelluq.discord.lavaplayer.player.DefaultAudioPlayerManager.<init>(DefaultAudioPlayerManager.java:121) 
        at com.bogsnebes.host_bot.bot.Bot.<init>(Bot.kt:26) 
        at com.bogsnebes.host_bot.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:11) 
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2615) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2784) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1523) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/INDEX.LIST"
        exclude "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
        exclude "META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties"
    }

    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bogsnebes.host_bot"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    ext.discord4j = "3.1.7"
    ext.lavaPlayer = "1.3.77"
    // LavaPlayer
    implementation("com.sedmelluq:lavaplayer:$lavaPlayer")
    // DiscordBot
    implementation("com.discord4j:discord4j-core:$discord4j")
}
```

Bot.kt

```
class Bot(private val id: String) : Commands {
    private val playerManager: AudioPlayerManager = DefaultAudioPlayerManager().apply {
        configuration.frameBufferFactory =
            AudioFrameBufferFactory { bufferDuration: Int, format: AudioDataFormat?, stopping: AtomicBoolean? ->
                NonAllocatingAudioFrameBuffer(
                    bufferDuration,
                    format,
                    stopping
                )
            }
    }.also { AudioSourceManagers.registerRemoteSources(it) }

    private val player = playerManager.createPlayer()
    private val provider: AudioProvider = LavaPlayerAudioProvider(player)
    private val discordBot = DiscordClient.create(id)
    private val scheduler = TrackScheduler(player)
    private var loop = false

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    fun init() {
        discordBot
            .withGateway { client: GatewayDiscordClient ->
                client.on(
                    MessageCreateEvent::class.java
                ) { event: MessageCreateEvent ->
                    val message = event.message
                    if (message.content.equals("По", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        return@on message(event, "Пе")
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!ping", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        return@on message(event, "Pong!")
                    } else if (message.content.contains("!play", ignoreCase = true) or message.content.contains(
                            "!p",
                            ignoreCase = true
                        )
                    ) {
                        play(event)
                        return@on message(event, "Песня поставлена в очередь")
                    } else if (message.content.contains("!next", ignoreCase = true) or message.content.contains(
                            "!skip",
                            ignoreCase = true
                        )
                    ) {
                        next(event)
                        return@on message(event, "Включена следующая песня")
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!queue", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        return@on showQueue(event)
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!loop", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        scheduler.loop = !loop
                        loop = !loop
                        if (loop) {
                            return@on message(event, "Повтор включен")
                        } else {
                            return@on message(event, "Повтор выключен")
                        }
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!shuffle", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        scheduler.shuffleQueue()
                        return@on message(event, "Очередь перемешана!")
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!stop", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        stop(event)
                        return@on message(event, "Прощайте!")
                    }
                    Mono.empty()
                }
            }
            .block()
    }

    override fun message(event: MessageCreateEvent, letter: String): Mono<Message>? {
        val message = event.message
        return message.channel
            .flatMap { channel: MessageChannel ->
                channel.createMessage(
                    letter
                )
            }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun join(event: MessageCreateEvent) {
        val member: Member? = event.member.orElse(null)
        if (member != null) {
            val voiceState = member.voiceState.block()
            if (voiceState != null) {
                val channel: VoiceChannel? = voiceState.channel.block()
                channel?.join { spec -> spec.setProvider(provider) }?.block()
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun play(event: MessageCreateEvent) {
        join(event)
        val message: String = event.message.content.toString()
        val command: List<String> = message.split(" ")
        playerManager.loadItem(command[1], scheduler)
        player.addListener(scheduler)
    }

    override fun next(event: MessageCreateEvent) {
        scheduler.nextTrack()
    }

    override fun showQueue(event: MessageCreateEvent): Mono<Message>? {
        val titles: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        var count: Int = 1
        for (i in scheduler.getQueue()) {
            titles.add(count.toString() + ". " + i?.info?.title.toString())
            count++
        }
        return message(
            event, titles.toString()
                .replace(",", "\n")
                .replace("[", "")
                .replace("]", "")
        )
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun stop(event: MessageCreateEvent) {
        val member: Member? = event.member.orElse(null)
        if (member != null) {
            val voiceState = member.voiceState.block()
            if (voiceState != null) {
                val channel: VoiceChannel? = voiceState.channel.block()
                channel?.sendDisconnectVoiceState()?.block().let { scheduler.clearQueue() }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class Bot(private val id: String) : Commands {
    private val playerManager: AudioPlayerManager = DefaultAudioPlayerManager().apply {
        configuration.frameBufferFactory =
            AudioFrameBufferFactory { bufferDuration: Int, format: AudioDataFormat?, stopping: AtomicBoolean? ->
                NonAllocatingAudioFrameBuffer(
                    bufferDuration,
                    format,
                    stopping
                )
            }
    }.also { AudioSourceManagers.registerRemoteSources(it) }

    private val player = playerManager.createPlayer()
    private val provider: AudioProvider = LavaPlayerAudioProvider(player)
    private val discordBot = DiscordClient.create(id)
    private val scheduler = TrackScheduler(player)
    private var loop = false

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    fun init() {
        discordBot
            .withGateway { client: GatewayDiscordClient ->
                client.on(
                    MessageCreateEvent::class.java
                ) { event: MessageCreateEvent ->
                    val message = event.message
                    if (message.content.equals("Попочка)", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        return@on message(event, "Пенис -_-")
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!ping", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        return@on message(event, "Pong!")
                    } else if (message.content.contains("!play", ignoreCase = true) or message.content.contains(
                            "!p",
                            ignoreCase = true
                        )
                    ) {
                        play(event)
                        return@on message(event, "Песня поставлена в очередь")
                    } else if (message.content.contains("!next", ignoreCase = true) or message.content.contains(
                            "!skip",
                            ignoreCase = true
                        )
                    ) {
                        next(event)
                        return@on message(event, "Включена следующая песня")
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!queue", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        return@on showQueue(event)
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!loop", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        scheduler.loop = !loop
                        loop = !loop
                        if (loop) {
                            return@on message(event, "Повтор включен")
                        } else {
                            return@on message(event, "Повтор выключен")
                        }
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!shuffle", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        scheduler.shuffleQueue()
                        return@on message(event, "Очередь перемешана!")
                    } else if (message.content.equals("!stop", ignoreCase = true)) {
                        stop(event)
                        return@on message(event, "Прощайте!")
                    }
                    Mono.empty()
                }
            }
            .block()
    }

    override fun message(event: MessageCreateEvent, letter: String): Mono<Message>? {
        val message = event.message
        return message.channel
            .flatMap { channel: MessageChannel ->
                channel.createMessage(
                    letter
                )
            }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun join(event: MessageCreateEvent) {
        val member: Member? = event.member.orElse(null)
        if (member != null) {
            val voiceState = member.voiceState.block()
            if (voiceState != null) {
                val channel: VoiceChannel? = voiceState.channel.block()
                channel?.join { spec -> spec.setProvider(provider) }?.block()
            }
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun play(event: MessageCreateEvent) {
        join(event)
        val message: String = event.message.content.toString()
        val command: List<String> = message.split(" ")
        playerManager.loadItem(command[1], scheduler)
        player.addListener(scheduler)
    }

    override fun next(event: MessageCreateEvent) {
        scheduler.nextTrack()
    }

    override fun showQueue(event: MessageCreateEvent): Mono<Message>? {
        val titles: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        var count: Int = 1
        for (i in scheduler.getQueue()) {
            titles.add(count.toString() + ". " + i?.info?.title.toString())
            count++
        }
        return message(
            event, titles.toString()
                .replace(",", "\n")
                .replace("[", "")
                .replace("]", "")
        )
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun stop(event: MessageCreateEvent) {
        val member: Member? = event.member.orElse(null)
        if (member != null) {
            val voiceState = member.voiceState.block()
            if (voiceState != null) {
                val channel: VoiceChannel? = voiceState.channel.block()
                channel?.sendDisconnectVoiceState()?.block().let { scheduler.clearQueue() }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer/issues/109 судя по всему lavaplayer не работает на адройде